# C++ bad allocation from heap fragmentation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I have the following problem.I run a loop for 3000 times. On every pass I allocate a byte buffer on the heap:

```
uint8_t* frameDest;
try { 
    frameDest= new uint8_t[numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t)];
    memcpy(frameDest, frameSource, _numBytes);
} catch(std::exception &e) {
    printf(e.what());
}
```

So the allocated frame serves as destination for a data from some frameSource._numBytes  equals 921600 .

Next, in the same loop frameDest is pushed into std::vector of uint8_t* pointers(_frames_cache).This vector serves as frames cache and being cleaned every X frame.With the current setup I clean the vector when more than 20 frames are in the cache.The method that cleans the cache is this:

```
void  FreeCache()
{
    _frameCacheMutex.lock();
    try {
        int cacheSize = _frames_cache.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < cacheSize; ++i) {
            uint8_t* frm = _frames_cache.front();
            _frames_cache.erase(_frames_cache.begin());
            delete [] frm;
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        printf(e.what());
    }
    _frameCacheMutex.unlock();
}
```

The issue:bad alloc exception is thrown after ~2000+ frames in the first code block.I tested for memory leaks with Dr.Memory and found none.Also I am getting no erros or exceptions on allocations/deallocation on other parts of the program.I have 2 instances of such a code running in 2 separate thread which means during the whole lifetime of this program some 6000 allocations / deallocations are processed, 960000 bytes each.In the whole app there are more heap allocs going on but not at the frequency as in this part.I have read that modern compilers handle heap management  in a pretty advanced way,and still,I suspect my issue has to do with memory fragmentation.I use Visual C++ 2012 compiler (C++ 11) ,32bit under Windows7 64bit OS.

My question is:how likely it is memory management  problem and should I write or use a custom heap alloc manager?If not,what could it be?

Comment: "Currently when it more than... " can you rephrase?

Comment: I edited that part.Sorry for typos.

Comment: 2000 * 900 mB? that's a lot Whoops kB

Comment: 2000x~1M is about 2G. Switch to 64bit.

Comment: `frameDest= new uint8_t[numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t)];` This is wrong: You never need a `* sizeof` with `new`. Just write `frameDest = new uint8_t[numBytes];` (and of course, `sizeof(uint8_t)` should be 1 anyway!)

Comment: @Roddy you are right but I don't think it's related to the problem.

Comment: @Mat ,going to try but can it be resolved with heap manager for 32bit?

Comment: If you stay anywhere near 2G on a 32bit system with 2G/2G split (default on Win32 AFAIK), you'll always risk having random allocation failures. If you want to stay 32bit, you'll need to manage your cache very, very carfuly (fixed size allocated at startup might be the sanest thing to do)

Comment: yep,when compiled under 64bit it works.

Comment: A `std::vector` of owning raw pointers o.O? Even if you *need* to use it, you shouldn't erase single elements from a `vector`. Every erase at the beginning is O(N)!

Comment: A 32-bit program running on a 64-bit Windows has full 4 GB of virtual address space.

Comment: @dyp  How should I delete them all then?

Comment: @MichaelIV Either use a `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> >` or delete all pointers in the loop (but don't erase them from the vector) and after the loop call `_frames_cache.clear()` (once).

Comment: Well clear cache is called also during runtime so the smart pointer wouldn't help.delete in the loop seems to be a better idea.Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelIV The idea of `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> >` is to *only* call `_frames_cache.clear()`, which will then automatically `delete` the individual frames via the dtor of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @dyp [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) is worth a look

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell if this is a memory fragmentation problem. But you may want to consider allocating a fixed amount of memory for your frames as a ring buffer at the beginning, so that during runtime you won't run into any fragmentation (and also save the time for memory (de)allocation). Not sure if this works with your use case, of course.